# What is the name of this mating pattern?

Tags: checkmate, terminology, patterns

Recently I delivered the mate shown below. Does it have a name?

```
[fen "1r5r/2p3pp/2R5/1pkPpp2/2b1P3/2K2P2/6PP/R7 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the closest one is called Hook Mate (see [Hook Mate Examples](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1030373)). But of course, there's a knight involved in it.

Comment: Nothing really fits for a rook+ pawn math with the king blocking off squares, that's beyond rare. Looks like he's getting swallowed by the sarlacc pit ;D

Comment: It's hard to really name mid-board checkmates since they are so rare it might not be practical to study them, so maybe that's why there's no name for this

Answer (score 2):

No, it's rather unusual (but beautiful!) to mate a King in the middle of the board. Because it's rare, probably nobody (that I know of) has coined a term for it yet.